# How to combine multiple rows into one column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following content (X represents some value)

| personal id | time point | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X |
| . | . | . |
| 1 | 12 | X |
| 2 | 400 | X |
| . | . | . |
| 2 | 411 | X |

Basically, for every person, I have labels for 12 consecutive time entries (not always from 1 to 12). What I want is the following form

| personal id | label (first time point) | label (seconde time point) | ... | label (twelfth time point) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | X | ... | X |
| 2 | X | X | ... | X |

How can I achieve this? Since I want to ignore the time point numbers and only want the twelve labels next to each other, pivot tables doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter by `personal id` and then use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.assign(g = df.groupby('personal id').cumcount()).pivot('personal id','g','label')
```